# Is Data stored using store.js persisted to the phone? Can up back it up to the cloud?

Tags: ios, cordova, icloud

I have an iOS PhoneGap app.  I'm storing some values using store.js.  This works great.  I'm a little confused about where this data goes.  Is it stored to the apps data?  So clearing the app's data from settings would remove it? Or is it stored with safari data?  If I back up my apps data using cloud back up, will it be retrieved if I restore the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your data was stored at [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/). Try this [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2010892/813307) issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored in the application sandbox and is not persisted to iCloud.

You need to write a phonegap plugin to handle persistence to iCloud, or send some ajax calls and do the persistence yourself.

I was trying to look around for an iCloud Phonegap plugin but have not found one yet.